# jQuery Mobile 1.4.3 fixed toolbar and page content issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm developing a web app using jQuery Mobile.
I have a single html file that contains more jQM pages.
These jQM pages have fixed headers and content loaded dynamically via jQuery (in this case I'm using a Listview with filtering option).

This is the HTML structure of all jQM pages:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="pageTemplateList">
<div class="ui-header ui-bar-a" role="banner" data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a role="button" data-role="button" href="#" class="ui-btn-left ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn ui-icon-action ui-btn-icon-notext" data-theme="a">Pubblica</a>
    <h1 aria-level="1" role="heading" class="ui-title">Videothron</h1>
    <a role="button" data-role="button" href="#panelMenu" class="ui-btn-right ui-alt-icon ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext" data-theme="a">Menù</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content" id="templateListViewContainer">
    <ul id="templateListView" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-hide-dividers="false" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Cerca template...">
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code that I call for moving between jQM pages is the following:

```
location.href = "#pageTemplateList";
```

When I move from the "first" page (in the image below is "BEFORE") to a "second" page and then come back to the "first" page (in the image below is "AFTER") the Listview content is positioned under the fixed toolbar and the filter input field is partially hidden.

[image]

What do you suggest to solve this issue? Do you need further information?

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Try with this dirty trick: `$(document).on("pageshow", "body", function(){ $(document).scrollTop(0); });` (sorry but without further information it's hard to suggest something else)

Comment: @Sga thanks for help but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed each single line of JS code until I found that this issue was caused calling this:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').trigger("create");
```

Removing this line of code (that I was calling after adding input text fields via jQuery) solved the issue.

Instead of calling `.trigger("create")` on the page div, create a div inside of the page div (eg. `<div id="insideThePageDiv">`) and call `.trigger("create")` for the inside div (eg. `$("#insideThePageDiv").trigger("create");`).